# Solving a system of three simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the system
$$
\begin{align*}
-2x + ay - bz &= -4 \\
x + bz &= 2 \\
2x + y + 3bz &= b
\end{align*}
$$
The question asks to find conditions on $a$ and $b$ that the system has no solutions, a unique solution or infinitely many solutions. If the system has many infinite solutions, what's solution in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I reduced the system to reduced echelon form. Now I'm stuck with it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the reduced echelon form you found?

Comment: i got x = b-2, ay + bz + 0, bz = b-4

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
-2& a & -b\\
1& 0 & b\\
2&1&3b
\end{pmatrix}$. Thus the system becomes:
$$M\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4\\2\\b\end{pmatrix}.$$

In order for there to be a unique solution, $M$ must be invertible, i.e. $\det M\not=0$. Expanding the determinant along the middle row yields
$\det M=-(3ab+b)-b(-2-2a)=b(1-a)$. Thus $b\not=0$ and $a\not=1$ guarantees a unique solution.

The remaining cases occur when $b=0$ or $a=1$. When $b=0$, we start by solving the bottom two rows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-4\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then to verify that the first row holds, we must have $(-2\ a)\cdot(2\ -4)=-4$, i.e. $a=2$. Since $z$ doesn't affect the solution, we have infinitely many solutions in this case:
$$
a=2,\ b=0,\ t\in\mathbb{R}:\qquad \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-4\\t\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now suppose $a=1$. In this case, we see that
$$0=(1\ 4\ -1)M\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=(1\ 4\ -1)\begin{pmatrix}-4\\2\\b\end{pmatrix}=4-b$$
Thus when $b\not=4$, there are no solutions, and when $b=4$, there are infinitely many solutions. To see why, solve the bottom two rows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&4\\2&1&12\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}\implies 
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2-4t\\-4t\\t\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thus to summarize, when $a\not=1$ and $b\not=0$ there is a unique solution, and in the remaining cases here are the solutions:
$$
(a,b)=\begin{cases}
(2,0),& \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-4\\t\end{pmatrix}\\
(1,4),& \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2-4t\\-4t\\t\end{pmatrix}\\
\text{else},&\text{no solutions}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Doing the elimination ($R_i$ is the $i$-th row)

- exchange $R_2$ with $R_1$;
- $R_2 \gets R_2+2R_1$;
- $R_3 \gets R_3-2R_1$;
- exchange $R_3$ with $R_2$;
- $R_3 \gets R_3-aR_2$

we arrive at the form
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & b & 2 \\
0 & 1 & b & b-4 \\
0 & 0 & b(1-a) & a(4-b)
\end{array}
\right]
$$

- If $b(1-a)\ne 0$, the system has a unique solution.
- If $b=0$ and $a=0$, the system has infinitely many solutions
- If $a=1$ and $b=4$, the system has infinitely many solutions
- If $b=0$ and $a\ne0$ or $a=1$ and $b\ne4$, the system has no solution